# Can vulkan interop with direct composition for window background blur effects?

Tags: winapi, vulkan, dxgi, direct-composition

Is it possible to use the Win10 compositor for 'acrylic blur' effects but use Vulkan for rendering?  It seems it might be by creating a DXGI swapchain and somehow using the Vulkan external memory extensions.  But I can't find any examples of this.

Also I don't know if its better to create a Vulkan swapchain and somehow share it to Direct Composition or create a D3D12 swap chain and somehow share that with Vulkan to render on?